# Exercise relating to FIR filter

Tags: low-pass, sampling, digital-filter, fir

I was trying to resolve a problem from "Understanding Digital Signal Processing". I have some questions about it. Why do we need to redesign the filter if we find out that the sample rate is higher? If we want to remove undesired high-frequency noise, should we keep the same FIR filter? I am looking for any other hints. Thank you!

P.S. I haven't seen in the same chapter any relationship of low-pass FIR filters with the sample rate of the original signal.[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework needs an attempt at a solution

Comment: Tell us why you think you would need to change the FIR coefficients, then reopen the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A digital filter deals purely with samples, and this is reflected throughout the analysis of the filter -- most remarkably, the properties of the filter like its passband, stopband, bandwidth, etc are given in *radians per sample* or equivalent units, rather than Hz and/or radians per second (as is the case with analog filters). In the end, if it's an FIR filter it's just a set of coefficients convoluted with the incoming sampled signal, sample by sample.

Suppose that the initial design specification were for a filter with a 5 kHz cutoff due to noise around 7 kHz. The engineer would design a digital filter with a cutoff of pi/2 radians per sample knowing that the sample rate was 20 kHz. Now, if those filter coefficients were used in a system operating at 40 kHz sampling rate, that cutoff of pi/2 radians per sample now corresponds to a 10 kHz cutoff, or a different filter than the desired one altogether which no longer attenuates the noise. The filter would thus need to be redesigned to attenuate the same noise.

Comment: So, if I will do "step by step" the convolution between the original signal and the first filter, the result for the 7 kHz frequency will be different than 0. So, I need to redesign the filter in order to make the amplitude of these frequencies (higher than 5 kHz) equal to 0?

Comment: That's correct. You'd redesign the filter for a cutoff of pi/4 radians per sample to meet the 5 kHz cutoff specification. Also be careful with the exact wording; I specified a 5 kHz cutoff but not a null at 7 kHz; the response for a 7 kHz sine will be very small but not necessarily zero.